# Logic & Reasoning Question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

At a track meet, every group of $n$ participants shares exactly one common friend.
Suppose runner $P$ has the largest number of friends. Determine how many friends $P$ has.

Assume for this question:

- $n \in N$ such that $n ≥ 3$
- Friends are mutual, EX: if $X$ is friends with $Y$, then $Y$ is friends with $X$
- No one is friends with themselves
- a group of runners has a "common friend" $a$ iff each runner in the group is friends with $a$

Prove the answer.

**Update for Clarification**

- $n$ is the size of the group, not the total number of attendees.
- There are an arbitrary number of groups
- The answer should be expressed in terms of $n$
- If $X$ is friends with $Y$ then both $X$ and $Y$ are at the trackmeet
- Assume there are at least $n + 1$ attendees.

Thank you very much for your effort so far @fleablood

Comment: This question appeared a day ago, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472289/mutual-friends-at-a-game.  Is it part of a contest?

Comment: No points challenge problem in my high school class. Thanks for pointing me to the duplicate. :)

Comment: Is it part of the assumptions of the question that if X is friends with Y, then X and Y are both at the track meet?

Comment: A solution is the tournament with n+1 people where they are all friends. But it seems a far more interesting problem to show that this is the only solution, or rather that other solutions also yield n as the maximum number of friends a runner can have.

Comment: @Zackkenyon Yes, if they're friends both are at the track meet. That is exactly what we're trying to prove. I apologize if the question was ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

P can't like as many as n people.

Label n of P's friends as $a_1,... a_n$.

$(P, a_1, ...., a_{n-1})$ have P as the mutual friend.  So $(a_1,..., a_{n-1})$ have no mutual friend.  So $(a_1, ..., a_n)$ have $a_n$ as a mutual friend.  So $(P, a_2, ...., a_n)$ have both P and $a_n$ as mutual friends.  Impossible.

So P has n-1 friends or fewer.

But as any group of n people have 1 mutual friend, that mutual friend has at least n-1 friends.  So P has at least n-1 friends.

So P has n-1 friends.

Comment: The claim "$(P, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1})$ have $P$ as the mutual friend" contradicts the assumption that nobody is friends with themselves.

Comment: No it doesn't.  The mutual friend is the guy who is friends with all the people except themself.  Thus the mutual friend is P.  If I used your definition then there'd be no common friends as no-one is friends with themselves.  Or is your issue with common vs. mutual?  I took those to be the same.  I'll edit to "common".

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying.  Dang it.